# Tomcat with 18080 port can see that web can success host, however, without any port doesnt show

Tags: java, tomcat

Currently I am hosting WAR with tomcat.

However, I find that if we host web by port 18080,
just like  http://my-server-site:18080/welcome

the page can show successfully.

However, if i just type :
http://my-server-site/welcome

it said cannot find directory '/welcome'.

Anyone have idea why looks weird?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not weird at all...

If you do not specify a port, it will default to 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS. I guess you have another web server (apache?) running on the same host that give you the error you see.

If you are expecting to see the same page on the default port, you will need to configure your web server as a proxy. `ProxyPass` for apache and `proxy_pass` for nginx.

Comment: thanks a lot, i added proxypass in conf file, and now can access through not specify port.